# PHP - redirecting to other page if there are no results

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to redirect the user to other page if there are no results.

what I meant like is, I am passing variables via url and using on the second page and if the the variables are empty I am able to redirect to another page.

However when the user changes the variable id in the url to something like

`index.php?product-tit/=how+to+deal+with%20&%20item-id-pr=15`

to `index.php?product-tit/=how+to+%20&%20item-id-pr=`

Nothing is displayed on the page so is there any way that I can redirect to other page in the above condition?

```
$title = urldecode($_GET['product-tit/']);
$id = $_GET['item-id-pr'];
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

if(empty($title) && empty($_GET['item-id-pr'])){
header('Location: products.php');
}
else{
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where title = ? AND id = ? limit 1 ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $id);
$stmt->execute();
?> 
<div>
<?php
$result = $stmt->get_result();
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo wordwrap($row['price'], 15, "<br />\n", true); 
}
$mydb->close ();}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you count result items and then re direct on the basis??

Comment: is that a typo `empty($GET_['item-id-pr'])` should be: `empty($_GET['item-id-pr'])`

Comment: oh yeah. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition requires both variables to be empty, if you want to redirect when any is empty you should use an OR (`||`):

```
if(empty($title) || empty($_GET['item-id-pr'])){
  header('Location: products.php');
  // make sure nothing more gets executed
  exit();
}
```

Also note that you cannot output anything to the browser before a `header` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing to check

1. Check the passed variable having some value or not. In this case you have already applied redirecting.
2. If user change URL params values like in your asked in example. You need to verify If database return any row corresponding to title and ID. If not redirect user to other page.

Here can be pseudocode

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['item-id-pr'];
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

// I am assuming variable name is "product-tit"
$title = urldecode($_GET['product-tit']);

if(trim($title) == "" || trim($_GET['item-id-pr']) == ""){
    header('Location: products.php');
    exit;
}
$stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM products where title = ? AND id = ? limit 1 ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

 if( $result->num_rows == 0 )  {
    // redirect user
     header('Location: products.php');
     exit;
 }
?> 
<div>
<?php
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo wordwrap($row['price'], 15, "<br />\n", true); 
}
$mydb->close ();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: it gives me `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_selected_rows() `

Comment: This redirects automatically with out waiting for `if` condition

Comment: I could not get what's going on exactly.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to redirect if the variables are empty?

Comment: I think there is some problem in your variable defining pattern variable name should not have /  (forward last). I am going to edit this again

Answer (score 0):

Test if the `$_GET` parameters are set and not empty *before* you assign them to other variables and do other stuff.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['product-tit/'], $_GET['item-id-pr'])
    || empty($_GET['product-tit/'])
    || empty($_GET['item-id-pr']))
{
    header('Location: products.php');
    // although note that HTTP technically requires an absolute URI
    exit;
}
// now assign $title and $id, initialize the db, etc
```